# Vector keeps appending rows to itself not replacing - java ( table & database )

Tags: java, resultset

```
Vector vect = new Vector();
Vector vect_container = new Vector();
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        rs.next();
        vect.addElement(rs.getInt("ID"));
        vect.addElement(rs.getString("Name"));
        vect.addElement(rs.getFloat("Price"));
        vect.addElement(rs.getDouble("Quantity"));
        vect.addElement(rs.getDate("datetime"));
        vect.addElement(rs.getString("person"));
        vect_container.add(vect);
    }
```

I am getting rows from a database table through `ResultSet(rs)`, but the vector is appending the results of all rows (not row by row). The output is:

```
[
    [23424234, Congestal, 10.0, 3500.0, 2013-03-23,
     Ahmed Ali, 34535647, Decksafeen, 35.0, 2000.0, 2013-03-23, Osama ], 
    [23424234, Congestal, 10.0, 3500.0, 2013-03-23,
     Ahmed Ali, 34535647, Decksafeen, 35.0, 2000.0, 2013-03-23, Osama ]
]
```

I believe that the first element in `vect_container` should be holding only the first row, and the second element should be holding both rows, and so on.

But that doesn't quite seem to be the case.

Comment: Move this line inside your loop: `Vector vect = new Vector();` Although you should use a list type and specify the generic type paramater. Even better would be to use an object representing your data instead of a list of strings. Further, my loop would be `while(rs.hasNext())`

Comment: `vect = new Vector();` should be **inside** your for loop.

Comment: wont that create a new vector for each row?
like if i have 1000 rows i will be having 1000 vectors !! 
iam asking just to understand

Comment: Already been answered - three times.

Comment: which? the main question or the one in the comments? @camickr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding the same `Vector` to `vect_container`. You need to add a new one in each loop iteration.

Move this line:

```
Vector vect = new Vector();
```

To after the rs.next() call:

```
rs.next();
Vector vect = new Vector();
```

Also, it's probably safe to not loop over the `ResultSet` that way. A more idomatic way is:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   Vector vect = new Vector();
   vect.addElement(rs.getInt("ID"));
   vect.addElement(rs.getString("Name"));
   vect.addElement(rs.getFloat("Price"));
   vect.addElement(rs.getDouble("Quantity"));
   vect.addElement(rs.getDate("datetime"));
   vect.addElement(rs.getString("person"));
   vect_container.add(vect);
}
```

Comment: i know i was testing how it will behave when adding one row

Comment: but does every time it creates a vector it deletes the one before ?? if not then how to get the first(or previous vector's value) ?? @Todd

Comment: @OmAr - It creates a new one every time (`Vector vect = new Vector()`) and adds it to `vect_container`. So you end up with a `Vector` that contains other `Vectors`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep loading data into the same Vector. You need to create a Vector for every row:

```
//Vector vect = new Vector();
Vector vect_container = new Vector();
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        rs.next();
        Vector vect = new Vector();
```